# Do Transformers have prisons?

Tags: transformers

One of the foundations of the *Transformers* franchise is that the Autobots and the Decepticons are engaged in a decades-long war with each other for the fate of the Transformer race. As is often the case in animated series (especially those from the 1980s), the two groups would frequently come to blows on a weekly basis with little headway made for either side of the conflict. Although occasionally one group captured a member of the other, rarely was that imprisonment long-term.

Do either the Autobots or the Decepticons have areas that can act as long-term prisons for what should really be considered prisoners of war? This question occurred to me after watching the live-action films directed by Michael Bay and noticing how Optimus Prime began to point-blank execute his fellow Transformers more and more frequently.

Comment: https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Trypticon_Prison / https://transformers.fandom.com/wiki/Alchemor_(RID) / https://tfumux.fandom.com/wiki/Kaon_Prison / https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Grindcore_(prison)

Answer (score 2):

In the Transformers universe there have been mentions of different prisons, some operated by Decepticons and some operated by Autobots.

**Prisons operated by Decepticons**

**Kaon Prison:** the Kaon prison is one of the worst on Cybertron. Several levels deep, it has special solitary containment cells for the worst of the worst on the bottom level. Interrogation rooms round out the dark and dismal corridors. Decepticons guard every cell, The entrances are more heavily guarded, by more powerful and alert warriors who take their duties seriously.

**Grindcore:** Grindcore is an infamous Decepticon prison camp. Maybe it's named after the pre-war Cybertronian, maybe not. Inmates are prevented from transforming by inhibitor spikes, which are implanted in the victim's mouth and violently shoot up into the brain module when they try to transform. Beatings, fuel poisonings and general horrific treatment are common, especially for anyone from the intellectual class. And worst of all are the "teleport chambers"... To name a few known workers:

- Charger
- Dreadwing or Dreadwind
- Flywheels
- Glit
- Octus
- Ruckus

**Prisons operated by Autobots**

**Alchemor:** Alchemor, also known as Decepticon Island, was an Autobot prison ship carrying some two hundred Decepticon prisoners under the custodianship of the Caretaker Mini-Cons Fixit, Toolbox and Cinch, along with many others. It crash-landed on Earth years after the defeat of Unicron and restoration of Cybertron, allowing many of its prisoners to escape confinement.

**Trypticon:** Trypticon Prison is the premiere Autobot detention facility on Cybertron. Located in the former Decepticon city-state of Kaon, it is where the worst of the worst spend the rest of their days thanks to the swift hand of Autobot justice.

Sources: [Trypticon](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Trypticon_Prison), [Grindcore](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Grindcore_(prison)), [Alchemor](https://transformers.fandom.com/wiki/Alchemor_(RID)), [Kaon Prison](https://tfumux.fandom.com/wiki/Kaon_Prison)

*courtesy of Valorum